# Protection, damage and Leyline of Punishment

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I was wondering about the following scenario:
I have a [Leyline of Punishment](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Leyline%20of%20Punishment) on board.
My opponent has [Auriok Champion](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Auriok%20Champion)
I cast [Anger of the gods](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Anger%20of%20the%20gods).

Will the damage from the [Anger of the Gods](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Anger%20of%20the%20Gods) still come through? As far as I'm aware, prevention by DEBT (Damage, Enchant/Equip, Block, Target) prohibits the damage according to rule 702.16e:

> 702.16e. Any damage that would be dealt by sources that have the stated quality to a permanent or player with protection is prevented.

However [Leyline of Punishment](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Leyline%20of%20Punishment) says damage can't be prevented. Or does the prevention by protection has priority over [Leyline of Punishment](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Leyline%20of%20Punishment)? If so, by what rule is this applied?

Comment: @doppel Protection doesn't seem like a good tag to have as a standalone tag.  Is there a reason you are adding it?

Comment: @bwarner Well, the same was done for Bestow. I don't mind really.

Comment: @bwarner so that we have a tag collecting questions on the same topic, helping people to locate other questions about the same. We do similar on [rpg.se] with tags that may differ in meaning between games, and it works fairly well. Given our mtg questions are almost entirely unclassified, it may help to at least collect questions together when they're clearly revolving around particular topics or mechanics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Champion will end up getting destroyed by the Anger of the Gods because of this rule.

> **101.2.** When a rule or effect allows or directs something to happen, and another effect states that it can't happen, the "can't" effect takes precedence.

So you have the Champion saying damage can be prevented, and the Leyline saying it can't be prevented so it isn't prevented.

Comment: I just thought protection had priority over other effects. Don't know why... I knew the most restrictive option will always be used. Thanks!